# Ways to invoke a function pointed by function pointer in C++

Tags: c++, c

I have noticed that there are two methods to invoke a function pointer in C++.

Example code:

```
void A(int x){
    ...
    ...
}

main() {
    void (*f)(int);
    f=&A;
    f();       //Method 1
    (*f)();    //Method 2
}
```

Why do both Method 1 and 2 work? And what is the logic for both methods having the same behaviour?

Comment: I had the same question some time ago. See the dup :)

Comment: Right :) I tried searching for duplicates before posting, but couldn't really locate it ..

Answer (score 1):

They both work and there's no difference between them. You should use one of them, whichever you find more readable, (i recommend `(*f)` version because it implies that `f` is a pointer to a function), but whichever you choose, please use it *consistently*.

Comment: Yes. (*f) in a way seems like de-referencing the function pointer, and then calling the function with appropriate arguements.
But then why does a direct call like f() work?